# Rotate Old Files

Tags: linux, mysql, cron, log-files, debian-jessie

I have a cron to backup 3 files every Hour, they are SQL backups - in the format `name-name-bak-2015-12-1919:30:01.sql`

I need a way to rotate and delete the older ones say every 7 days?

Thought of using log rotate and looking for advice

I'am Using Debian 8

Thanks

Chris

Comment: So, did you try logrotate? Did it work? What problems do you still have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a logrotate script, you can create a file, and add it to /etc/logrotate.d/

This is the file script content:

```
/yourfolder/name-name-bak-*.sql {
       weekly
       missingok
       rotate 14
       compress
       delaycompress
       notifempty
       create 640 root root
}
```

In this case:

- `weekly` it will be run once per week
- `missingok` If the log file is missing, go on to the next one without  issu-
            ing an error message
- `rotate 14` Log files are rotated 14 times  before  being  removed  or
            mailed to the address specified in a mail directive. If count is
            0, old versions are removed rather then rotated.
- `compress` Old  versions  of log files are compressed with gzip by default.
- `delaycompress` Postpone  compression of the previous log file to the next rota-
            tion cycle.  This has only effect when used in combination  with
            compress.   It  can be used when some program can not be told to
            close its logfile and thus might continue writing to the  previ-
            ous log file for some time.
- `notifempty` Do not rotate the log if it is empty
- `create 640 root root` Set user group and rights to the rotated files

**more information on the man page :** http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

To launch manually (or test) your script, you can use the following command:

```
logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/yourfilename
```

Comment: Np ! i added the command to launch logrotate manually if needed